# Filtering by CharField choices text property

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How could you filter by the choices text instead of the choices key?

Suppose you have the following CharField in a model:

```
CHOICES = ( ('FI', 'First'), ('SE', 'Second'), ('TH', 'Third') )
choiceField = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHOICES)
```

Then you try to filter it in a view like so:

```
query_in_choice_field = Model.objects.filter(choiceField__contains=query)
```

*query is a string, it could be 'third', or 'ir'*

This filter only checks 'FI', 'SE' and 'TH'.

How would you filter by 'First', 'Second' and 'Third'?

Comment: What is `query` in your snipper?

Comment: Query is a string. It could be 'thi' for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box. The second value from a CHOICES-tuple is the value which is being displayed in a dropdown in the Django-admin for example. The first value is the one that's being stored in the database.

What you could do is filter it in python instead of trying inside the database-query, e.g.

```py
def get_containing(choices, needle):
    containing = []
    for k, v in choices:
        if needle in v:
            containing.append(k)
    return containing


query = 'ir'
qs = Model.objects.filter(choiceField__in=get_containing(Model.CHOICES, query))
print(qs)  # Objects where selected choice is 'FI' or 'TH'
```